# API Platform only accepts arrays for doctrine type json_array, how can you save strings?

Tags: json, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have a Symfony 4.4 doctrine class like this:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "GET" = {"security"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"},
 *          "POST" = {"security_post_denormalize"="is_granted('EDIT', object)"},
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *          "GET" = {"security"="is_granted('EDIT', object)"},
 *          "PUT" = {"security"="is_granted('EDIT', object)"},
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"="my_symfony_class:read"},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"="my_symfony_class:write"},
 *     attributes={
 *          "pagination_items_per_page"=30,
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_symfony_table")
 */
class MySymfonyClass
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="default_value", type="json_array", nullable=true)
     *             @Groups("my_symfony_class:read","my_symfony_class:write")
     */
    private $defaultValue;
}
```

But when I want to PUT an object with defaultValue set to a JSON string "0" to the API platform endpoint, API platform gives this error message:

```
"The type of the \"defaultValue\" attribute must be \"array\", \"string\" given."
```

The error seems to be the same as [How to save json attribute via ApiPlatform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598063/how-to-save-json-attribute-via-apiplatform) but with the difference that I don't assert as JSON ("@Assert\Json()").

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is for example what i use.
Depending on your doctrine version, it might not work.

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'json', options: ["default" => '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'])]
private array $openDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Using symfony and doctrine json type; You do not have to set json yourself, just use php array and it will json_encode / json_decode automatically when flushing to database / retrieving from database.

Regarding your @Assert\Json(). It can not work because it validate that your `string` is a json valid string.
But when using doctrine type `type: 'json'`, your php type is not `string` but `array`.
They can not work together.

About your problem, this is not related to api platform but to doctrine.

Also, to avoid problem like this one, i advise you to type EACH property. It will cost you little time comparing to time gained to understand futur problem. It will help you to have better understand of what you do too. In that case, that a doctrine json type is always related to a php array type.